# MongoDB Driver Query * Filter Definition Builder * Nin $nin Not in filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

Has anyone used the C# .Net MongoDB Driver FilterDefinitionBuilder's not in filter? This is a simple example that I put together that I cannot seem to get to work. Assume that we must keep the collections as is. The goal is to retrieve only ArtistDetailsDocument's that are not in the specified ArtistGenresDocument list.

The code will not compile and states "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'MongoDB.Driver.FieldDefinition ArtistDetailsDocument,ArtistGenresDocument' because it is not a delegate type".

Appreciate the help! \m/ \m/

```
public class ArtistDetailsDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public String artist_ID { get; set; }
    public String artistName { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistGenresDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public String artist_ID { get; set; }
    public String genre { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<ArtistGenresDocument> list = await ArtistGenresCollection.Find(x => x.genre == "Pop" | x.genre == "Easy Listening").ToListAsync();

var filter = Builders<ArtistDetailsDocument>.Filter.Nin<ArtistGenresDocument>(x => x.artist_ID, list);

var ArtistDetailsDocuments = ArtistDetailsCollection.Find(filter);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution with help from pieperu!

```
IEnumerable<ArtistGenresDocument> list = await ArtistGenresCollection
    .Find(x => x.genre == "Pop" || x.genre == "Easy Listening")
    .ToListAsync();

var filter = Builders<ArtistDetailsDocument>
    .Filter
    .Nin(x => x.artist_ID, list.Select(l => l.artist_ID));

var ArtistDetailsDocuments = await ArtistDetailsCollection
    .Find(filter)
    .ToListAsync();

public class ArtistDetailsDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public String artist_ID { get; set; }
    public String artistName { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistGenresDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public String artist_ID { get; set; }
    public String genre { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Glad i couldn help. If my post was useful perhaps you could upvote, there may be some useful info in there for others

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull the Artist_Id from the collection of objects that are being returned by your first query, you are currently comparing your entire objects collection to the Artist_ID field in your second query

You can achieve this either with the Project() method on the query after your find:

```
.Project(x => x.artist_ID).ToListAsync()
```

or by using linq after the results have been returned

```
list.Select(l => l.artist_ID)
```

**NOTE :** I assumed the field here owlud be artist_ID, so you may need to change artist_ID to whatever the field is on your ArtistGenresDocument model

Try something like this (i also corrected a few other bugs in your code)

```
IEnumerable<ArtistGenresDocument> list = await ArtistGenresCollection
    .Find(x => x.genre == "Pop" || x.genre == "Easy Listening")
    //This is where your projection would go if you didnt use linq
    //.Project(x => x.artist_ID).ToListAsync()
    .ToListAsync();

var filter = Builders<ArtistDetailsDocument>
    .Filter
    //This is where we are plucking the Artist id with linq
    .Nin<ArtistGenresDocument>(x => x.artist_ID, list.Select(l => l.artist_ID));

var ArtistDetailsDocuments = await ArtistDetailsCollection
    .Find(filter)
    .ToListAsync();
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This makes a lot of sense...Thank you. However, the error continues to persist when I hover over "x => x.artist_ID"

Comment: If you hover over "list" and inspect the items within it, what fields do you have as I guessed artist_ID? And what is the latest error

Comment: The error was the same as above. I just figured it out... by removing the <ArtistGenresDocument> from the Not in filter. I have tried removing this earlier but it had no effect until I had added your Linq expression. I will post the modified solution. Thanks for your help!!! :)

Comment: Of course. Sorry I should have spotted that. That's what you get for copy and pasting :) glad you got it working, and happy if I was of any help